# Remove discount from Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

Basically, a client needs to provide a discount that offers free shipping over a certain item total. Easy enough. But the discount needs to only apply to one shipping method, not all.

I can easily display no shipping charge, but if a customer chooses a shipping method that they should still be charged for, I am unable to remove the free shipping discount.

So it's this issue:

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/181

Does anyone have a work around?

Like is there a quick and dirty business logic few lines of code to remove a discount programmatically?